# How some apps are able to perform google login successfully in android webview?

Tags: android, webview, google-signin

As described [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) google has stopped supporting google login in `webview`. But there are apps in play store (all-in-one apps) who are displaying multiple progressive apps in their apps using `webview` and we can login there using google login.

So my question is how we can make this possible.

I have searched for questions on SO with following query.

> Android 403: Error: Disallowed Useragent

Found lot of accepted answers with some of them containing various `UserAgentString`

Tried all of them but none of them helped. As `UserAgentString` doesn't helps always.

If login is being performed by opening new window then it doesn't work. Even though we define same `UserAgentString` with `webview` in `onCreateWindow` callback of `WebChromeClient`.

I have also tried searching for alternative of `webview` like `CrossView`  etc. but they are not maintained from last 3 years.
I can't use `custom chrome tabs` as I can't hide address bar of `custom chrome tab`.

So please suggest me if it's really possible in `webview` or is there any alternative to `webview`.

**EDIT** - What I have tried so far.

**WebView Initialization in onCreate()**

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36");
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
}
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
enableHTML5AppCache(webView);

webView.loadUrl("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
```

**Supporting methods and classes**

```
private void enableHTML5AppCache(WebView mWebView) {

    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

    // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
    // But it didn't work for me without this line
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/cache");
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
}

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg) {
        WebView newWebView = new WebView(getActivity());

        newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        newWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            newWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
        enableHTML5AppCache(newWebView);
        newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                webView.removeView(window);
            }
        });
        view.addView(newWebView);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(newWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        webView.removeView(window);
    }
}
```

Now, when I am using above `UserAgentString` google login is working where it's getting performed within same `webView`. But in above site when you click on `login->google` then it request for new window(I have return code above for new window - see `onCreateWindow()` method above) then it shows `error 403 - Disallowed UserAgent`.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] to show what you have tried. Also give links to the questions you found and explain how your question is different.

Comment: Also, provide examples of apps which use webviews for google login.

Comment: Note that the link you gave describes alternatives to using webview for google login.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have edited question, added what I have tried and what is expected. Please check.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Check [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chimbori.hermitcrab) and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inone.in). where you can see google login in progressive apps available in these apps is working fine.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Would you please define how my link have the alternative for `webview`? As we can't hide address bar of `custom-chrome-tab` so I can't use `custom-chrome-tab`. I want alternative `webview`  where we can hide it's address bar.

Answer (score 17):

webSettings.setUserAgentString(webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("; wv",""));

then  you can login .

Comment: Yeah, now I'm not getting any error like 403. But after putting the password its struck in the google loading screen. How to handle this problem

Comment: it used to work but now it doesnt

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks correct.

Google OAuth blocks WebView based on the user agent string, using your own user agent string makes the login available again (actually you only need to remove the "wv" from the original string).

Unfortunately there is a bug in WebView that when the `setSupportMultipleWindows` option is enabled the first navigation in the newly created WebView uses the default user agent string. See the bug tracker for more details: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614951

The bug is fixed in Chromium 67 (the current version is 66), so the next version of WebView is expected to work fine. I haven't tested this myself though.

So either disable multiple windows support or wait for the next version of WebView to reach the users (if you really need a workaround you might experiment with reloading the page after first navigation or something similar).

Comment: I had exactly that problem: the new webview (which is already created and configured) has the right user agent (the same as the original). But it fails.
Disabling multiple windows (which is not ideal for me) works.
I wonder if I could just load a first bogus page on that popup browser (even if not visible), and then have it work...
In fact: "New WebView for popup window must not have been previously navigated." I cannot workaround it...